# How to add all available value or label filters from a pivot table into a listbox? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, filter, listbox, pivot, vba

Okay, so I have a pivot table where there is a column of provinces and other columns of sales per years.

I have created macros through vba to apply filtering on the pivot table.
(Recorded macros)

I want to add all available label and value filters into a listbox eg:

Label filters are : 
Equals...
Does not equal... 
Begins with...

Etc...

I want all of them in a listbox, or combobox, or anything the user can click and expand to select what filter they want.

Any help please?

jamesalainheffer@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Okay well I seemed to have figured it out. Most people don't know about the filtering options in excel. And if they do, they probably would go about doing it in VBA by saying something like

```
`With 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvt_Data").PivotFields("Province")`
```

.PivotItems("Yukon").Visible = false

and so on... By just making the field or item not visible, doesn't neccessarily mean you're applying a filter to anything...

So, here's what I found...

```
dim prov as string
dim letter as string 
dim val2 as string 
dim pvtPivotTable as PivotTable
dim pfdValueField as PivotField
dim pfdTRowField as PivotField
set pvtPivotTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvt_Data")
set pfdValueField = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Sum of Sales")
set pfdTRowField = pvtPivotTable.PivotFields("Province")
letter = TextBox4.Value 
prov = TextBox1.Value
msg = ", Caption Filters, " & listbox1.value
with pvtPivotTable
.AllowMultipleFilters = True 
pfdTRowField.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=Listbox1.Value, Value1:=prove, Value2:=letter
end with 
set pfdValueField = nothing 
set pfdRowField = nothing 
filterlistbox.AddItem(Listbox1.Text & " " & prov & msg
```

now what this does along with the rest of my projects is it loads every xlFilterType into 3 listboxes, per categpry of Caption filters (text), Value Filters (numerical), and date filter (date)

3 listbox's for 3 categories of filter types, each listbox is loaded with them (filter types [xlBefore, xlCaptionIsEqual]) when you select a filter type, enter a value into a textbox and push a button and it weill then apply that filter onto my pivot table.

The listbox where the filter type gets added I did like this:

```
.addItem("Equall...")
.list(0, 1) = "15"
```

What this does is add that "Equall" to the list box, the list statement just inserts 15 into the 2nd column on the 1 st index (index starts at 0, 1 is the 2nd column)

Now, the xlFilterTypes have a value as well as a name for example XlCaptionEqualls is the name and its value is 15, the listbox1.value is this value becuase i set the bound column to number 2, so the listbox pushes out the filterTypes value (number) instead of the text I hard coded, you can then use case statements to get the name from the value and insert them into another listbox.

this is a bit all over the show but I would like to know if nayone has managed to add multiple filters onto their pivot table using vba? and the add2 method?

Kick ass.